# Creating a gRPC client connection with the WithBlock() option to an asynchronously started gRPC server blocks indefinitely?

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I'd like to write a unit test in which I run an ephemeral gRPC server which is started in a separate Goroutine within the test and stopped after the test runs. To this end, I've tried adapting the 'Hello, world' example from this tutorial (https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/) to one in which instead of a server and a client with separate `main.go`s, there is a single test function which starts the server asynchronously and subsequently makes the client connection using the `grpc.WithBlock()` option.

I've put the simplified example in this repository, https://github.com/kurtpeek/grpc-helloworld; here is the `main_test.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "testing"
    "time"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld"
)

const (
    port = ":50051"
)

type server struct {
    helloworld.UnimplementedGreeterServer
}

func (s *server) SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *helloworld.HelloRequest) (*helloworld.HelloReply, error) {
    log.Printf("Received: %v", in.GetName())
    return &helloworld.HelloReply{Message: "Hello " + in.GetName()}, nil
}

func TestHelloWorld(t *testing.T) {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    require.NoError(t, err)

    s := grpc.NewServer()
    helloworld.RegisterGreeterServer(s, &server{})
    go s.Serve(lis)
    defer s.Stop()

    log.Println("Dialing gRPC server...")
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(fmt.Sprintf("localhost:%s", port), grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithBlock())
    require.NoError(t, err)
    defer conn.Close()
    c := helloworld.NewGreeterClient(conn)

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    log.Println("Making gRPC request...")
    r, err := c.SayHello(ctx, &helloworld.HelloRequest{Name: "John Doe"})
    require.NoError(t, err)
    log.Printf("Greeting: %s", r.GetMessage())
}
```

The problem is that when I run this test, it times out:

```
> go test -timeout 10s ./... -v
=== RUN   TestHelloWorld
2020/06/30 11:17:45 Dialing gRPC server...
panic: test timed out after 10s
```

I'm having trouble seeing why a connection is not made? It seems to me that the server is started correctly...

Comment: check to see if `s.Serve(lis)` is returning an error. Maybe the port is in use from another terminal process?

Comment: the `net.Listen` would error if the port was in use - but maybe there's some other bootstrapping error that `err := s.Serve(lis)` may reveal.

Comment: I've checked that `s.Serve(lis)` does not return an error (by invoking it like `go require.NoError(t, s.Serve(lis))`).

Comment: Ok that may not be the issue but FYI: never run a goroutine like that i.e. `go f1(f2())` - because the parameters are evaluated *before* the go-routine is created. So if `f2()` blocks, your main goroutine will block. So instead do: `go func() { err := f1(f2()) }()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems the code you posted here has a typo:

`fmt.Sprintf("localhost:%s", port)`

If I run your test function without the `grpc.WithBlock()` option, `c.SayHello` gives the following error:

```
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address localhost::50051: too many colons in address"
```

The culprit seems to be `localhost::50051`

After removing the extra colon from the `const` declaration (or from  `fmt.Sprintf("localhost:%s", port)`, if you prefer), the test passes.

```
const (
    port = "50051" // without the colon
)
```

Output:

```
2020/06/30 23:59:01 Dialing gRPC server...
2020/06/30 23:59:01 Making gRPC request...
2020/06/30 23:59:01 Received: John Doe
2020/06/30 23:59:01 Greeting: Hello John Doe
```

However, from the documentation of `grpc.WithBlock()`

> Without this, Dial returns immediately and connecting the server happens in background.

It follows that **with** this option, any connection errors should be returned straight away from the `grpc.Dial` call:

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial("bad connection string", grpc.WithBlock()) // can't connect
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // should panic, right?
}
```

So why does your code hang?

By looking at the source code of `grpc` package (I built the test against `v1.30.0`):

```
    // A blocking dial blocks until the clientConn is ready.
    if cc.dopts.block {
        for {
            s := cc.GetState()
            if s == connectivity.Ready {
                break
            } else if cc.dopts.copts.FailOnNonTempDialError && s == connectivity.TransientFailure {
                if err = cc.connectionError(); err != nil {
                    terr, ok := err.(interface {
                        Temporary() bool
                    })
                    if ok && !terr.Temporary() {
                        return nil, err
                    }
                }
            }
            if !cc.WaitForStateChange(ctx, s) {
                // ctx got timeout or canceled.
                if err = cc.connectionError(); err != nil && cc.dopts.returnLastError {
                    return nil, err
                }
                return nil, ctx.Err()
            }
        }
```

So `s` at this point is indeed in `TransientFailure` state, but the `FailOnNonTempDialError` option defaults to `false`, and `WaitForStateChange` is false when the context expires, which doesn't happen because `Dial` runs with the background context:

```
// Dial creates a client connection to the given target.
func Dial(target string, opts ...DialOption) (*ClientConn, error) {
    return DialContext(context.Background(), target, opts...)
}
```

At this point I don't know if this is intended behavior, as some of these APIs as of `v1.30.0` are marked as experimental.

Anyway, ultimately to make sure you catch this kind of errors on `Dial` you can also rewrite your code as:

```
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(
        "localhost:50051", 
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()),
        grpc.FailOnNonTempDialError(true),
        grpc.WithBlock(), 
    )
```

Which, in case of a bad connection string, fails immediately with the appropriate error message.